# Selecting UsedRange in Columns and Rows in Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

- I have two sheets in my excel file, `DTMGIS` and `DTMEdit`
- the `DTMEdit` sheet is empty
- and I am trying to xopy  everything from `DTMGIS` and Paste only Values to Sheet  `DTMEdit`

I do not know how to select the `UsedRange` only and paste this to `DMTEdfit`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCoulmn As Long, Header As Long
Header = 2
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")
LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
LastCoulmn = ws.UsedRange.Column.Count

With ws.UsedRange
    .Select
    .Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub CopyPasteValues()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMEdit")

    ws1.Range(ws1.UsedRange.Address).Copy
    ws2.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Soren just can can you please let me know what is .UsedRange.Address ?

Comment: No problem. That returns the address of the used range in a given worksheet. In this case the address of the used address in `DTMGIS`.

Comment: @SørenHoltenHansen `A1` may not be the start of the `UsedRange` on the first sheet

Comment: @brettdj How is that a problem? `UsedRange` returns the range regardless of the first cell in the range.

Comment: Because you are copying to A1 ratter than replicating the underlying sheet - and A1 may not be the start of the UsedRange from the source sheet.

Comment: That is true, but that doesn't appear to be a ciriteria in this particular case. :)

Answer (score 0):

A variation below which

- avoids the assumption that the `UsedRange` starts from A1
- runs the copy without moving the formats as well (if you do use `.Copy` use `Application.CutCopyMode = False` at the end)

*code*

```
Sub FastCopy()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMEdit")
    ws2.Range(ws1.UsedRange.Address).Value = ws1.UsedRange.Value
End Sub
```