# How To Copy All Value From Sheet One and Paste to Rest of Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

Can some one please let me know how I can copy values from sheet1 and paste them to teh rest of existing values?
I have two sheets called "DTMGIS" and "DTMFinal" they have exactly same structure but I need to add values from "DTMGIS" to end of (I mean after Last Row)  "DTMFinal"?

I already got this code from Soren at this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717826/selecting-usedrange-in-columns-and-rows-in-sheet) which works for me on copying in an empty sheet but for appending data to existing I think I need something more

```
Sub CopyPasteValues()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMEdit")

    ws1.Range(ws1.UsedRange.Address).Copy
    ws2.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub CopyPasteValues()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMGIS")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DTMEdit")

    With ws1
        Set rng1 = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        Range(.Cells(1, 1), rng1).EntireRow.Copy
    End With
    With ws2
        Set rng2 = .Cells.Find("*", .Cells(1, 1), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If rng2 Is Nothing Then
            .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            rng2.EntireRow.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Updated to avoid `UsedRange`

Comment: Hi Chris , thanks for code it is working but there are some issue. when I run the code for the first time it Cut all values from sheet 1 and paste to sheet 2. Also after first run if you enter new values it will add two empty rows at the end of destination sheet before pasting the code

Comment: `UsedRange` can return more than you expect, if some cells have been used and cleared (can be just formating).  Updated code to remove `UsedRange`.  As to the `Cut` question, I can reproduce that, code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a General Solution to ur Question, Soluton can be made more specific if you can provide some sample data to be copy pasted

General Solution as follows :

```
    Sub CopyPaste()

'Copying Data
Sheets("DTMGIS").Activate
Range("A1").Select
'    DataStart = Selection.Address
'    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
'    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
'    DataEnd = Selection.Address
'    Range(DataStart, DataEnd).Select
'    Uncomment The Above 5 lines if u have Multiple columns of data
'    and Comment the Below line.
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy


' Pasting data
Sheets("DTMFinal").Activate
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) = 0 Then     'Checking If Sheet has no data
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
Else
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
End If


End Sub
```

Feel Free to ask for any modifications in the code. As there was no sample data I have made some asumptions..